# r - character vector with byte order mark (UTF-8-BOM) behavior differs between operating systems

Tags: r, byte-order-mark

I have a script that ingests a file or connection that sometimes may have a UTF-8 [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). I wrote this line to handle stripping out the unwanted characters:

```
text_wo_BOM <- sub(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x5e, 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf))), "", text_with_BOM)
```

However, while doing so, I noticed that my GNU-Linux environment did not print the characters but my Windows environment did. Both are running R 3.4.x.

**Linux**

```
rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)))
## [1] "﻿"
```

**Windows**

```
rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)))
## [1] "﻿ï»¿"
```

Pattern matching behavior appears to be the same between GNU-Linux and Windows, *e.g.*, `grep`, `sub` `regexpr`. However, for some operations Linux does not count the BOM as characters but Windows does. As a result, functions such as `substr` or `substring` will behave differently depending on the operating system.

**My Question**

Is there any way that I can force my Linux machine to mimic Windows' behavior or vice-versa?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it might be related to your locale settings. Do you have the same output if you run `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: I think you're on to something. **Linux**: `en_US.UTF-8` **Windows**: `English_United States.1252`. One cannot be set to the other, though.